# Postgres full text search and spelling mistakes (aka fuzzy full text search)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I have a scenario, where I have data for informal communications that I need to be able to search. Therefore I want full text search, but I also to make sense of spelling mistakes. Question is how do I take spelling mistakes into account in order to be able to do fuzzy full text search??

This is *very briefly* discussed in [Postgres Full Text Search is Good Enough](http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/) where the article discusses misspelling.

So I have built a table of "documents", created indexes etc.

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
  text TEXT NOT NULL);
```

I can create an additional column of type tsvector and index accordingly...

```
alter table data 
  add column search_index tsvector 
  generated always as (to_tsvector('english', coalesce(text, ''))) 
  STORED;

create index search_index_idx on data using gin (search_index);
```

I have for example, some text where the data says "baloon", but someone may search "balloon", so I insert two rows (one deliberately misspelled)...

```
insert into data (text) values ('baloon');
insert into data (text) values ('balloon');

select * from data;

id |  text   | search_index
----+---------+--------------
 1 | baloon  | 'baloon':1
 2 | balloon | 'balloon':1
```

... and perform full text searches against the data...

```
select * from data where search_index @@ plainto_tsquery('balloon');

 id |  text   | search_index
----+---------+--------------
  2 | balloon | 'balloon':1
(1 row)
```

But I don't get back results for the misspelled version "baloon"... So using the suggestion in the linked article I've built a lookup table of all the words in my lexicon as follows...

> "you may obtain good results by appending the similar lexeme to your tsquery"

```
CREATE TABLE data_words AS SELECT word FROM ts_stat('SELECT to_tsvector(''simple'', text) FROM data');

CREATE INDEX data_words_idx ON data_words USING GIN (word gin_trgm_ops);
```

... and I can search for similar words which may have been misspelled

select word, similarity(word, 'balloon') as similarity from data_words where similarity(word, 'balloon') > 0.4 order by similarity(word, 'balloon');

```
  word   | similarity
---------+------------
 baloon  |  0.6666667
 balloon |          1
```

... but how do I actually include misspelled words in my query?

Isn't this what the article above means?

```
select plainto_tsquery('balloon' || ' ' || (select string_agg(word, ' ') from data_words where similarity(word, 'balloon') > 0.4));

         plainto_tsquery
----------------------------------
 'balloon' & 'baloon' & 'balloon'
(1 row)
```

... plugged into an actual search, and I get no rows!

```
select * from data where text @@ plainto_tsquery('balloon' || ' ' || (select string_agg(word, ' ') from data_words where similarity(word, 'balloon') > 0.4));

select * from data where search_index @@ phraseto_tsquery('baloon balloon'); -- no rows returned
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here - can any shed any light? I feel like I'm super close to getting this going...?

Comment: Use `to_tsquery` and construct a string with `|` between the alternatives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT to_tsquery('balloon |' ||
                  string_agg(word, ' | ')
       )
FROM data_words
WHERE similarity(word, 'balloon') > 0.4;
```

Comment: LOL, thanks.... I can do this...

 select text, ts_rank_cd(search_index, 'balloon | correctly') 
   from data 
  where search_index @@ (select to_tsquery(string_agg(word, '|')) 
                           from data_words 
        where word % 'baloon') 
  order by  ts_rank_cd(search_index, 'baloon');

is this really the way you're supposed to do fuzzy full text search though? I mean it sort of works, but at the same time I can't escape the feeling that I'm missing something (or a lot of somethings)...

Comment: I guess so. There are no provisions for fuzzy full text search in PostgreSQL. You might investigate a synonym dictionary that contains all possible spelling mistakes.

Comment: Ultimately, this sort of query is as close as I think I'm going to get... Thanks for your help!

`select text, ts_rank_cd(search_index, 'baloon')
   from data
  where search_index @@ (select to_tsquery(string_agg(word, '|'))
                           from data_words
  where word % 'baloon')
  order by  ts_rank_cd(search_index, 'baloon') desc;`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this thread, the accepted answer by @laurenz-albe needed a slight modification for me:

It required single quotes around the argument values passed to the `string_agg` function, which can be done using the [`format function`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) along with the `%L` placeholder.

This updated code worked for me:

```
SELECT to_tsquery('balloon |' ||
              string_agg(format('%L', word), ' | ')
   )
FROM data_words
WHERE similarity(word, 'balloon') > 0.4;
```